# Create SQLite Database before using it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

I want to store some data like name and class of different students in form of SQLite database.
**I want to develop an application which uses this data not fill it**. I mean application should not fill it.
My application will use this data to make a report. This database should be bundled with my android app

So how to create this database on android?
How to bundle this database with the app on android?
I mean my file should be an apk but when installed it should have this database also

Please kindly give your advice

Yours Sincerely,
ChinniKrishna Kothapalli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to do that :

1) Create a file containing your SQLite database into your assets folder

2) When you want to access your database, check if /data/data/yourpackage/databases/yourdatabase.db exists

3) If it doesn't exist, copy it from your assets to /data/data/yourpackage/databases/yourdatabase.db

4) Call SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (it takes a path in parameters)